# How to Code a Recursive Function by Vector in R?

Tags: r, recursion, max

I have a function : **(1 - (x / d))**
which d is members of a vector (V)
Based on length of the vector, a function will be like this:
for example vector is V [2, 3.5, 5, 4.1]
so the function would be:

```
[(1-(x/2))*(1-(x/3.5))*(1-(x/5))*(1-(x/4.1))]
```

if I give it an other vector like [1.5, 2] function would be:

```
[(1-(x/1.5))*(1-(x/2))]
```

that means the function's shape depends on length of my vector and its elements.
I want a code to create this function and then find its maximum by optimize in R.

Comment: What is `x` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way. Function `f` returns a function that can be applied to a vector `x`.

```
f <- function(d) {
  force(d)
  function(x) prod(1 - x/d)
}

d <- c(1.5, 2)
g <- f(d)
sapply(1:5, g)
#[1] 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.5000000 1.6666667 3.5000000
```